# How to enable setting a field for which I want no validation rule?

Tags: php, validation, yii

I have an active form model which has fields I do not wish to set any validation rules for. The problem is that Yii does not set these fields when I submit the form unless I assign *some* validation rule to them.

The fields are optional and free-form, so I don't want to assign a validation rule. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the special ["safe"](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.model#declaring-safe-attributes) rule:

> Sometimes, we want to declare an attribute to be safe, even though we
>   do not really have any specific rule for it. An example is an
>   article's content attribute which can take any user input. We can use
>   the special `safe` rule to achieve this goal.

```
$rules = array(
    'myfield' => 'safe',
);
```

This rule does not place any restrictions on the field (so you are free to leave it empty); it just tells Yii that you want the field to be set on the model whenever the model is populated from an external source.